# How to group by and sum operations Datatable

Tags: linq, group-by, sum

this is my datatable

```
Id    Article    Lot      Ordered      Unit Shipment    Difference
1     32207      21309    80           Case 80          0
2     32218      21309    70           Case 60          10
3     32237      22359    50           Case 50          0
4     32255      24299    100          Case 100         0
5     32207      24299    110          Case 110         0
6     32218      21309    80           Case 75          5
7     32237      21309    60           Case 60          0
8     32255      21309    75           Case 75          0
```

I need Group By for columns Article and Lot, and Sum quantity columns (Ordered, Shipment And Difference).

The expected result would be:

```
Article Lot Ordered Unit    Shipment    Difference
32207   21309   80  Case    80          0
32218   21309   150 Case    135         15
32237   22359   50  Case    50          0
32255   24299   100 Case    100         0
32207   24299   110 Case    110         0
32237   21309   60  Case    60          0
32255   21309   75  Case    75          0
```

I wish to obtain the result using Linq.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much

Comment: What have you tried? You can use a DataTable as an enumerable via the AsEnumerable extension method. Apart from that, take a look at the [GroupBy functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341740.aspx) on an enumerable (and plenty of other methods).

Answer (score 0):

try to cast it to an **enumerable** then use linq

**UPDATED**

```
from v in mytable
group v by new {v.Article,v.Lot} into g
select new
{
    Article = g.Key.Article ,
    Lot = g.Key.Lot ,
    Ordered = g.Sum(X=>X.Ordered),
    Unit = g.First(),
    Shipment = g.Sum(X=>X.Shipment),
    Difference = g.Sum(X=>X.Difference) 
}
```

Comment: You need to group by article **and** lot.